# why Image is not loading in django template?

Tags: django, django-templates

I uploaded a picture in the Django database but when I try to show this picture in Django templates, it's not showing anything but showing the image title.
Here is my **index.html**

```
{% for value in data %}
    <div class="product-box">
        <div class="img-wrapper">
            <div class="front">
                <a href="product-page(no-sidebar).html"><img
                        src="{{ value.product_img.url }}"
                        class="img-fluid blur-up lazyload bg-img" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <div class="back">
                <a href="product-page(no-sidebar).html"><img
                        src="{{ value.product_img.url }}"
                        class="img-fluid blur-up lazyload bg-img" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <div class="cart-info cart-wrap">
                <button data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#addtocart"
                    title="Add to cart"><i class="ti-shopping-cart"></i></button> <a
                    href="javascript:void(0)" title="Add to Wishlist"><i
                        class="ti-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> <a href="#"
                    data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#quick-view"
                    title="Quick View"><i class="ti-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                <a href="compare.html" title="Compare"><i class="ti-reload"
                        aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="product-detail">
            <div class="rating"><i class="fa fa-star"></i> <i class="fa fa-star"></i> <i
                    class="fa fa-star"></i> <i class="fa fa-star"></i> <i
                    class="fa fa-star"></i></div>
            <a href="product-page(no-sidebar).html">
                <h6>{{ value.product_title }}</h6>
            </a>
            <h4>{{ value.price }}</h4>
            <ul class="color-variant">
                <li class="bg-light0"></li>
                <li class="bg-light1"></li>
                <li class="bg-light2"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

**Here is my views.py**

```
def home(request):
    context={
            'data': Products.objects.all()
        }
    return render(request, 'auctionApp/index.html',context)
```

[image: Here is a picture of where it's is not showing product image in web page but showing title and price]

Comment: Did you set up a media path for development?

Comment: Lets see your settings.py and project urls.py

Comment: Thank.. I didn't set media url in urls.py file. I forgot that. Thanks again

Comment: You are welcome. don't forget to add what solved your problem as an answer so others who stumble on the same issue can easily fix it with your answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just add below **code** in `urls.py` file in the project directory:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```